# For a disk within a ring, why is arclength proportional to $R*\theta$ but not $a*\phi$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, geometry

Here is an example problem, why is $\phi$ not by itself in the constraint equation? Can someone explain this geometrically? It seems like the curve of the surface curves *away* from the disk, but that seems hand-wavy and incorrect.

[image: Trouble!]

Comment: $\phi$ appears in the constraint equation as $-\phi = (R/a - 1)\theta$? I do not fully understand your question.

Comment: s is not proportional to just a*phi but is proportional to R*theta, why is that?

Comment: Check my answer. I've included a detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Can you convert the picture of the text into typed-out, formatted text? It makes the content index-able by search engines, and shows up better on different devices' displays. For formulae, try [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the surface that the sphere is on isn't flat. If it were flat, the distance would just be $a\phi$.

Think of it this way: Imagine a marking on the edge of the sphere that is originally facing upwards. On a flat track, after having rolled one round, $2\pi a$, the marking will still be pointing up. This is also true for a curved track. However, notice that it will no longer point toward the center of the curved track, which we will call the radial direction. In other words, the "upwards" direction no longer coincides with the radial direction, but is instead offset by an angle $\theta$.

In your case, which is a concave track, the sphere has to roll an angle $\theta$ *less* because it has translated by a distance $2\pi a$, but the track has curved *towards* it by an angle $\theta$. Which is to say, the upwards direction is now *ahead* of the radial direction by an angle $\theta$. Thus, it has to roll an angle $-\theta$ in order for the marking to point radially again. Hence the opposite signs of $\theta$ and $\phi$ in the equation.

For a convex track, the sphere has to roll an *additional* angle $\theta$ because it has translated by a distance $2\pi a$, but the track has curved *away* from it by an angle $\theta$. Which is to say, the upwards direction is now *behind* of the radial direction by an angle $\theta$. Thus, it has to roll an angle $\theta$ in order for the marking to point radially again.

Why do we bother with the radial direction at all? Well, this is because the *center* of the sphere and the point of contact with the track both lie on the radial direction. It is the only direction that doesn't change with respect to the track, always remaining perpendicular to it. Imagine a small circle travelling around a larger, stationary circle, with its point of contact fixed. By travelling one round, it would have rotated once, even though it *never* rolled with respect to the larger circle!

To summarize, no matter which direction you use, the center and the point of contact do not travel the same distance, which would be the case on a flat surface, and this discrepancy must be accounted for.

Check out the Coin Rotation Paradox for more details.

Comment: Thank for you the answer! One more question, so the smaller disk's point translates to 2*pi*a, but the arclength traveled, will be greater or less because of the curvature of the surface it rides on. I wish there was more information on this behavior! I'm checking out this paradox, it's definitely been messing with my head! I should have used a coin earlier, it has been bugging me.

Comment: @walczyk: Yes, you are correct. Rolling without slipping can be thought of as the superposition of pure translation and pure rotation. That is, it is the combination of "moving without rotating" and "rotating on the spot". So, by this argument, the curvature of the surface requires more or less rolling than if it were flat, because the *center* of the object doesn't travel the same distance as the *point of contact*. I was bugged by this problem myself when I first came across it, and also took some time to understand it. Take your time, it isn't something everyone gets immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add a picture to better visualize the equation of constraint. Hope it helps someone out there. I've called the angle related to the rotation of the sphere $\gamma$ and I've drawn the situation for when $\gamma=\pi$.

[image: Rotating sphere on a curved surface with radius of curvature]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

\begin{align*}
&\text{Position vector }\\\\
 R_2&=
\begin{bmatrix}
  (R-a)\,\sin(\varphi_1)+a\,\sin(\varphi_2) \\
 (R-a)\,\cos(\varphi_1)+a\,\cos(\varphi_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\\\
&\text{Velocity :}\quad v=\sqrt{\dot{R}_2^T\, \dot{R}_2}=v(\varphi_1\,,\varphi_2\,,\dot{\varphi}_1\,,\dot{\varphi}_2)
  \\
  &\text{At the contact point is: $\varphi_2=\varphi_1\,\Rightarrow\quad v=v(\dot{\varphi}_1\,,\dot{\varphi}_2) $}\\
  &\text{Motion without slipping}\quad \Rightarrow\quad 
  v_c=v(\dot{\varphi}_1\,,\dot{\varphi}_2)\overset{!}{=}0\\
  &\Rightarrow\\
  \dot{\varphi}_2&=-\frac{R-a}{a}\dot{\varphi}_1
  \quad \Rightarrow\quad  {\varphi}_2=-\frac{R-a}{a}{\varphi}_1
\end{align*}